# how can i add all possible routes from A to B in a custom maps in google map

Tags: google-maps

I am creating a custom map using google maps which is showing direction from the A to B. I want to show all the possible routes from A to B. When adding a direction from A to B in a custom map it gives me only a one route. How can i get the all possible routes for a given destination from a starting point

Answer (score 7):

You may set `provideRouteAlternatives` to `true` in the `DirectionsRequest` in order get multiple routes from the `DirectionsResult` object.

Here's what is stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DisplayingResults):

> Generally, only one route is returned for any given request, unless the request's **provideRouteAlternatives** field is set to true, in which, multiple routes may be returned.

Then in order to display all the routes in your map, you may get the `overview_path` from each route and store it in a `Polyline` array and then pass that array to `polylineOptions` property of the `DirectionsRenderer` object.

Here's a sample [code](http://jsbin.com/ripahuq/edit?html,css,js,output) of what I'm suggesting.

Here's the embedded code as well

```js
var map;
var polyOptions =[];  

function initMap(){
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    removeLine(polyOptions);
    polyOptions = [];
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService,directionsDisplay);
  });
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService,directionsDisplay) {

  directionsService.route({
    origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
    destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    provideRouteAlternatives : true

  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var pathPoints ;

        for(var i = 0; i<response.routes.length; i++){
          var routeLeg = response.routes[i].legs[0];
          pathPoints = response.routes[i].overview_path;
          var polyPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: pathPoints,
            strokeColor: "Blue",
            strokeOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeWeight: 5,
            map: map
          })
          polyOptions.push(polyPath);
        }
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 
        directionsDisplay.setOptions({ 
          polylineOptions: polyOptions,
          suppressPolylines : true
        });

      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function removeLine(options) {
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
    options[i].setMap(null);

}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Multiple Routes</title>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <strong>Start:</strong>
      <input id="start" type="text" value="chicago">
     <strong>End:</strong>
     <input id="end" type="text" value="Oklahoma">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Get Route">
    <!--   <br> -->
    </div>
  
    <div id="map"></div>
    
     <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB7fqfSyuj-jkh9cNGL63Jin5t4aHXIRUE&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

.